# Org-mode - table columns alignment - little tweak

Tags: emacs, org-mode

In org-mode when I am using tables I need either to set up somehow or change algorithm of alignment in columns.

By default there is text aligned to right with one whitespace character prepended. If you insert more characters then these are removed. I need to keep all characters in table as they are, without any unwanted modification. There are some means of modification in table header by using  or  but that is not enough. So i need either to find some hidden settings, or to modify a function that makes this alignment magic. How can I do that?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want?  The pre-pended space is simply to differentiate it from the `|` that is use for table alignment, if you export the table (to csv for example) the added spaces aren't included.  To get the table alignment correct it will either have to add spaces before or after your text otherwise the columns will no longer add up.

Comment: Well for example if i write |<SPACE><SPACE>code... then I would like to have code string indented 2 (or 3) characters instead of one.